# C# Adding code to FormClosing event disables X on MdiParent

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, formclosing

I have two background threads and a thread to handle minimization running on my WinForms Application. When the program closes, I use this method.

```
private void MyForm_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(labelsUpdaterThread.IsAlive == true)
            labelsUpdaterThread.Abort();
        if(printNotifyThread.IsAlive == true)
            printNotifyThread.Abort();
        if(minimizeThread.IsAlive == true)
            minimizeThread.Abort();
    }
```

labelsUpdaterThread and printNotifyThread run all the time. MinimizeThread, as you might guess, only runs when the parent form is minimized. Here's my problem:

When the thread.abort methods are called in my above method, the "X" on the top right of my MdiParent form doesn't do anything. Clicking it has no effect.

When the thread.abort methods are NOT called in my above method, closing the MdiParent will sometimes throw exceptions because the Threads are still trying to access resources on the MdiParent that are no longer available, even though they are background threads!

I'm unsure as to why this is happening, doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you are not doing any validation that could cancel a close event, you should be using `FormClosed` instead of `FormClosing`.

Comment: Please don't edit the sample code in the question. This may cause answers given earlier to look incorrect.

Comment: @unholy: FormClosed happens after the Form closes. My application then throws exceptions because they are trying to access resources on the closed thread.

Comment: @jdv: Sorry about that, but in all honestly, it doesn't seem that your answer was correct in the first place. But I do understand the necessity to keep the question the same. I'll refrain from changing it in the future.

Comment: @Everyone: Wish you could bump here, still have no solutions! :(

Comment: @Jason: I've come to realize that. >:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with [Paul Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598484/c-adding-code-to-formclosing-event-disables-x-on-mdiparent/4598554#4598554) in that you should *never* call `Thread.Abort`, it's a horrible way to handle synchronization.

Additionally, you have a horrible separation of concerns here.  The threads should not access resources in the form directly.  There should be some sort of abstraction/shared-state in between, which is modified and read by both sides (the thread and the form, so make sure to make the instance thread-safe).

That said, if you couldn't make those changes then in the Close method, call the `Thread.Abort` methods in another thread with a try/catch statement around each.  Log the error(s) somewhere at least.

In performing the calls to `Thread.Abort` on another thread, you don't block the UI thread, as the calls to `Thread.Abort` are not guaranteed to be instantaneous, and blocking the UI thread will cause the X to be greyed out while the UI thread cannot process Windows Messages (it also helps to guide you to a better separation of concerns).

However, you should move to abstract out the resources that are shared between the form and the thread, as well as provide a proper cancellation mechanism.

If you abstract out the resources to a class that shares the state, then your form doesn't have to do anything on close, the thread call stacks have a reference to the object that has the state and you can then call abort on those threads without worrying about the form and the threads sharing anything.

From there, you can then introduce a proper cooperative cancellation mechanism ([cooperative cancellation, which Task supports in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx), if that's available to you).

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge, how would calling Thread.Abort from another Thread with try/catches help my case? How is it different from surrounding what I currently have with try/catches?  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @CODe: In putting the calls to `Thread.Abort` on another thread, you aren't blocking your UI thread which is the cause of your problem in the first place (the X being disabled).  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks! The new thread worked. For now, I'm satisfied with this quick fix, but I'll be pushing for the abstraction you talked about in the next few days. My employer only let's me work a certain number of hours each day unfortunately. ;) I appreciate your contribution very much!

Answer (score 0):

The Abort calls are probably throwing exceptions. Make sure that the pointers are valid and threads are still valid (not disposed) before calling abort.

And, in visual studio, open Debug\Exceptions... and set a check in the 'thrown' column for all exceptions so you see when something goes wrong.

Comment: Changed the Exceptions, it threw this exception on the first thread.abort.         "User code running on thread 5736 has attempted to abort thread 5692. This may result in a corrupt state or resource leaks if the thread being aborted was in the middle of an operation that modifies global state or uses native resources. Aborting threads other than the currently running thread is strongly discouraged."

Comment: So what is the correct behavior for closing a WinForms Application when you have background threads running?

Comment: @CODe: A more safe way would be to set a flag that the app is closing, make sure that all backgrounds threads check it regularly and finish if they see it is set. Then do a `Join()` on the thread to wait for it to shut down. I tend to prefer `BackgroundWorkers` when running threads in GUI apps, but thats even more rework.

Comment: @jdv: Are you suggesting an approach similar to Paul Alexander's answer? I've tried it out, unfortunately it didn't work. It just freezes the entire application.

Comment: @CODe: I tend to agree that calling `Thread.Abort` is a bad idea. Or even using raw .net threads in general. But I also feel that you learn more from making mistakes, rather than listening to other people. Is your thread regularly checking if it is shutdown time now?

Comment: @jdv: Unsure as to what you are referencing with "shutdown time", unless it's what I had said didn't work in the comment above yours. Also, I wouldn't be here if I didn't value other people's opinions and knowledge. I'd be perusing google.

Answer (score 0):

First, Delete the calls to .Abort() and never use them again. Threads should never be terminated by calling Abort. It basically crashes your thread and doesn't give it a chance to release any resources properly or free any system handles.  Instead create a `ManualResetEvent` and check that in your threads. When the event is set, they should terminate.

Thread1

```
while( ! _stopEvent.WaitOne(0) )
{
  ...do my thready work

}
```

Then in closing

```
private void MyForm_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  _stopEvent.Set();
  labelsUpdaterThread.Join();
  ...
}
```

If you don't care if the threads terminate properly on application exist, just set `IsBackground = true` and they'll be terminated automatically when the application exits.

Comment: Doing the above, and clicking on the X now results in locking my entire application without throwing an exception as it was doing before. It just freezes. :/

Comment: It will only lock your application if your threads do not properly monitor the _stopEvent. They should be periodically polling to see if the event is set and if so, return from the main thread function. You might want to read up on threaded programming to better understand the implications. Concurrent Programming on Windows is an excellent resource (http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/032143482X?ie=UTF8&tag=xi00-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=032143482X).

Comment: Also, setting IsBackground = true for your threads will let .NET terminate them automatically when the app exits - won't lock up your app.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what happened when I tried your solution then. The threads have a 5 second wait, with a     while(!_stopEvent.WaitOne(0)), AND my threads are background threads, and the program still froze. Thanks for the reading reference by the way, I'll drop by Barnes and Noble and see if I can pick one up, or at least something similar.